# Windows 10 slows down in about ~2 minutes after log on

Tags: windows, performance, login, troubleshooting, debug

Problem:
~2 minutes (seconds after my wallpapers auto change ) after log on, almost everything becomes very very slow. Game like Forza motosport 6 APEX, Resident Evil 7 seems not be affected even in Window (not full screen) mode.

Problem still after trying:

- I check and use SysinternalsSuite\ **Autoruns** / msconfig / Task Manager / Schedule to close all the items for a clean boot.
- Create a empty **new user profile**.

Checks:

- Use SysinternalsSuite\ **procexp**, Event logger, didn't find much.
- ***Services***

  > - I found the **exact time** as same as the sluggish occurs when I was comparing the Services difference between the boundary of sluggish.
  > - That is **NetSetupSvc - Network Setup Service**, which is auto run by trigger and auto stop, when it stops everything become sluggish.
  > - And no matter how to set the run type - by manual, even disable; either run it again after it auto stops.
  >     There must be some relationships, such as who triggers it to run and to stop.
- Use **Windows Preferences Analyse** (WPA).

  > - Some system process starts and stops seconds around everything goes slow.
  > - Could found high UI Delays \ COM Delay occurs when right clicking on folders in taskbar.
  >
  >   ---
  >
  > See **Boot_Trace.rar (V3)**
  >
  > - At *https + ://share.weiyun.com/d342aed77fe831840e3bca95ae74d794*.
  >     (I can only post max 2 links default expired on July, 14).
  > - In environment where closed almost all the items (see Autoruns),
  > - With some heavy mouse operation - right click between folders -on taskbar  to see if system slows down(explorer.exe - untime Broker、ShellExperienceHost).
  > - **Seizing** happens at the ~100th second, when high **CPU occupied** with the operations above.
  >
  >   ---
  >
  > Also see **slowWindowsShell result**.
  >
  > - https: + //share.weiyun.com/82873c8f2a064edbce126cb294674e78 (I can only post max 2 links, default expired on July, 16)
  > - A ETL result of WPA record profile by @magicandre1981 , talked / details in comment of this question.
- Use msconfig to **log boot**:

  > There are 200 rows of records excluding duplicates. [Original content](https://share.weiyun.com/ca79d369f886bfa446d2e60d67908eb7) (expired at July 15).
  >   I try to compare both, but found little relativity. Sort by loaded
  >   item (*.sys),
  >
  > - Normal boot loads much more items;
  > - Safe mode has its own items;
  > - Safe mode didn't load some items which not appears in normal mode;
  > - Records on the same item has different state - loaded & not loaded;
  > - ...
  >
  > More doubts:
  >
  > - There are two **state** - BOOTLOG_LOADED / BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED. Does BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED means abnormal?
  > - Or, can I make any future configs to **adjust** from normal boot to safe mode?
- **System Restore** Node

  > - Maybe the division before this problem, I keep my computer always on / sleep long time before a reboot.
  > - And the Restore node is already lost, now I'm not sure how to *restore*, or even *delete* them manually, I used a driver update tool to do this but without backup.
  > - See [System Restore.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pfvd.png)
- **Disk**

  > CrystalDiskInfo on System is fine (I can only upload max 2 links now).
  >   Can't see *other* SSD and Hard Drivers on my PC, maybe I disable too many in Autoruns?
  >   When system slows down, the **4K write speed** as typical showed by AS SSD Benchmark reduce from normal 150MB/s to 30MB/s, etc.

Other info:

- **Log of**f / **Sleep**, then log on, could re-produce the problem.
- **Safe mode** is fine.
- Seems some drivers were updated some day before, seen from System Auto Backup, but the point was delete/covered now.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of Win10 SDK) and run this command from a cmd.exe which was started as admin to capture a boot trace: **xbootmgr –trace boot -traceFlags BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+DRIVERS+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+NETWORKTRACE+PERF_COUNTER+POWER+PRIORITY+REGISTRY -postBootDelay 300 -resultPath C:\Boot_Trace**. postBootDelay 300 captures 5 minutes of activity after boot

Comment: when you open the ETL do you see now activity after 2 minutes?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Update post. Didn't see Now Activity in any process.

Comment: the CAB is not helpful. You need to zip and share the large ETL file

Comment: @magicandre1981Updated. 100+M

Comment: ok, some processes start and do some work which leas to CPU usage, but does this really slow down your 6700K so much that you notice this? Download this file from my dropbox, reboot, after logon open a cmd.exe as admin and run **wpr -start C:\PathTo\slowWindowsShell.wprp -start ReferenceSet -fileMode** wait until you see the slowness and capture 1 minute of the activity. After 1 minute is over, go back to the cmd and type **wpr -stop slowWindowsShell.etl** now zip and share this new ETL + the ngenpdb folder

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's very sluggish after the minutes. Right menu on taskbar delay for almost 1 sec, type is sluggish, but in game like Resident Evil it is fine, sometimes little block.And, I found the file from another post of you. But can **stop** prompt that "An Event session cannot be started without any providers. 5580612". I use WPR to do this with the same result, only if combine your profile with "ReferenceSet". Should I record them separately?

Comment: It's strange, if I starts it right after log on, it fails when Stop, but some time after log, it could be done (to stop and save). Now I get a record in normal mode - with all items auto started (It failed totally in my clean boot). And did some operations such as right clicking on taskbar folders, result see [slowWindowsShell](https://share.weiyun.com/82873c8f2a064edbce126cb294674e78). Also updated in topic.

Comment: I still have no real idea what is slow.update the GPU driver to 384.76, also try the [Samsung nVME driver 2.2](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/downloads/software/Samsung_NVM_Express_Driver_22.zip). Also try the inbox driver of Windows even if this river gives you lower benchmark values. Also reduce the number of tools that run at startup .

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, I can't find any clues, I'm curious too. Even exclude all the **startup items** which shouldn't slow system so much before. Only in **safe mode** everything is fine, and in the **game** too (test Resident Evil 7 / Forza motosport 6 APEX)?! So, I doubt there's something wrong with the **driver**, but I didn't find a way to specify and switch them one by one for testing.

Comment: I upload an picture captured from the **System Restore** point which compared the new and old items that changed. And the Restore node is already lost, now I'm not sure how to restore or even **delete** them manually, I used a driver update tool to do this but without backup. Also **log boot** record something about the driver (not) loaded. @magicandre1981

Comment: safe mode loads only a minimal set of drivers/services. so disable some 3rd party drivers / tools until you see what slowdowns windows too much. and update the 2 mentioned drivers.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I found the exact time as same as the sluggish occurs when I was comparing the Services difference between the boundary of sluggish.
That is NetSetupSvc - Network Setup Service, which is auto run by trigger and auto stop, when it stops everything become sluggish. And no matter how to set the run type - by manual, even disable; either run it again after it auto stops. There must be some relationships, such as who triggers it to run and to stop. Is any suggestion to check this?

Comment: And, when system slows down, the 4K write speed showed by AS SSD Benchmark reduce from normal 150MB/s to 30MB/s, etc.
BTW, I updated all the drivers. And delete intel rapid storage which will slow SSD where AS SSD benchmark shows the speed. Updated, see Services, Disk@magicandre1981

Comment: this is a good question. Run the feedback hub app, create a feedback hub with your finding about the NetSetupSvc (Network Setup) Service. share a link here so that I can notify my contacts about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run `msconfig.exe` in run and enable bootlog for debug which process have problem with check boot log.  Then you can see what’s happened in boot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're being pretty thorough. I'm curious what the "normal process" was that stopped just before it triggers? I'd like to see that boot trace to see if I can help.

And to confirm, you've ruled out hard drive failure with something like CrystalDiskInfo, so you are dealing with a software glitch for sure? (Takes 2 minutes to download, install and run.) The reason I ask is, I've seen computers with bad drives boot alright, then grind to a complete halt once they hit a difficult to access file. You never know where bad sectors will land, and when they just start to show up, they very often trigger only for certain software or at certain moments. And yes, they can reliably trigger for that one program.

If you have checked your hardware / SMART info, then disregard and continue.

Comment: Eh.. I'll correct it. "normal process" above means some *system* processes start and end around time. I'm not sure if it is normal or not.
Upload the ETL (cab) file, see WPA.
Upload the [CrystalDiskInfo result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r48Za.png). I checked disk using chkdsk in volume property menu. Your diagnose is right. I omit the infos that I use SSD as system driver, and there are hard drivers. BTW ruled out drive failure, also because safe mode is fine, and fault happens regularly.